# Making Horizontal Lines Longer?

Tags: rules, line

I'm trying to use a resume template and my current problem is once I modified the page margins to 1.0in all around, the horizontal lines don't reach my location/dates on the right side like they used to.

[image]

The only code I can find referring to this in the template is this:

```
% Use to draw horizontal line with specific thickness
\def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which resume template do you use? Please add a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: @ferahfeza I'm sorry I can't find the base template right now. I have a link I can share to view/edit my resume on Overleaf that uses the template but I don't know if I want to share my PII publicly... Any way I can private message you the link?

Comment: You can give here the Overleaf link without including your personal data.